# Jquery: all inputs with id matching regex or filter?

Tags: jquery

I need to find all inputs with jquery which ids either match the string completely or match pattern `id + "-" + [0-9]`. In the form there are also inputs and divs with ids that match pattern `id + "-" + some_other_string` but I need to exclude these. I thought about using something like `$("#" + string) || $('input,select').filter(function(){ return this.id.match(string+/[0-9]) })` but I am not sure if that is the best approach. Is there something better?

Comment: perhaps you can double think about your HTML design then?

Comment: It is not designed by me, I have to work with what I've got I'm afraid.